# keep on getting "could not connect to device" on nexus 6p <--> mac

Tags: adb, usb, file-transfer, nexus-6p

This used to work reliably for me all the time. Simply connecting my nexus 6p to my mac, tapping on the `file transfers` option in the `USB for file transfer option` and boom

[image: Use USB for Popup]

but now I keep on getting this screen

[image: Could not connect Screen]

It's not a big surprise.. I've always got that screen but simply restarting the phone or unplugging the USB and then replugging it worked (sometimes I had to turn off developer options for it to work).

But now none of these procedures work

## What I do know

- I know it's not a physical problem with the usb cable.. because I can access my phone using `adb ssh` just fine
- I've also turned off my adb server just in case etc

Ideas?

## Note:

If I type in `adb devices` on my shell i get this

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
8XV5T15A29004531        device
4df727de4f8c110f        unauthorized
```

which is weird.. I do know my 6p id is `8XV5T15A29004531`.. so i'm not quite sure what this unauthorized thing is, although i ran `adb kill-server` just in case but that didn't change anything.